# Rotate MTLTexture

Tags: ios, rotation, metal

I'm using Metal to display camera frames. I convert the outputted sample buffers into `id<MTLTexture>`s using `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`, and that works great... except that the frames come rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

How can I rotate the `id<MTLTexture>` 90 degrees counter clockwise?

I considered doing this when I display the texture (in the `MTKView`), but then it will still be rotated the wrong way when I record the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least a couple of different options here.

The easiest is probably requesting "physically" rotated frames from AVFoundation. Assuming you're using an `AVCaptureConnection`, you can use the `setVideoOrientation` API (when available) to specify that you want frames to be rotated before they're delivered. Then, displaying and recording can be handled in a uniform way with no further work on your part.

Alternatively, you could apply a rotation transform both when drawing the frame into the Metal view and when recording a movie. It sounds like you already know how to do the former. The latter just amounts to setting the `transform` property on your `AVAssetWriterInput`, assuming that's what you're using. Similar APIs exist on lower-level AVFoundation classes such as `AVMutableComposition`.